# How to implement a re-sizable and auto hide side menu

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a re-sizable side menu and I want to set it to zero width when the context in it is empty.

I could implement one of these features but have on idea how to implement them both.

Is that possible to re-size the `max-width` of the parent container and let the child extend to this width?

https://codepen.io/wwcong/pen/gOrPRZO

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `:empty` css selector. [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)